# How to install Epson L220 printer

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS a few days before. Now I want to print some file with my Epson L220 Inkjet All-in-One printer. Ubuntu automatically adds the printer, but unable to print any text(.txt file) or PDF file.
[image]
The printer simply bypasses the A4 paper with no printing on the paper. Why this happens and what is the way out form this problem?

Comment: Download the drivers from [this site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) and open with Software Install.

Comment: From this site, I download the **deb** file epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb , and open via Software Center, which goes to the new page "Epson Printer Utility for Linux" , and install it . But still print is not done

Comment: @user68186 A4 paper selected , no at first save in test editor and then print

Comment: Finnaly fix this problem , manually add Epson L210 during printer setting, in Add printer button , and my printer works well and print also successfully printed.

Comment: Please write your own detailed answer with all the screenshots and then accept that answer as the correct one by placing the green tick mark ✅ on the left margin of the answer. This will help others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to Settings and then click on *Devices* → *Printers*.

   [image]
2. Then click on *Additional Printer Settings...*.

   [image]
3. Click on *Add*.

   [image]
4. Select your own printer from the *Device* tab and make sure that the connection is USB (if your printer is connected via USB) and then click on the *Forward* button.

   [image]
5. If your computer is connected to the internet, it should automatically start searching for a driver and you have to choose your model number and corresponding driver(recommended). Then *Select printer from database* and click *Forward*.

   [image]
6. Select your printer's brand (like Epson or HP or others ) and click *Forward*.

   [image]
7. Select your printer's model number and recommended driver and then click *Forward*.

   [image]
8. Click *Apply*.

   [image]
9. You are done. If you want to print a test page, click on the *Print Test Page* button.

   [image]
10. The printer is successfully added.

    [image]

That's all. Enjoy printing with your Epson printer in your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: No, all I have done is that without deb file . Simply from settings only .

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept your answer as the correct one after the waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers helped. However, I had to do a lot more to get it working. Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm from [Espson driver support site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=34541&DSCCHK=141ba614c212ead0099d27f8dc8f2bc35faf7781)

2. CD to the Downloaded folder
3. Install the cups filter in ubuntu from the downloaded folder using command

   sudo alien -i epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm
4. Extract the downloaded file to new folder.
5. Navigate inside the extracted folder and find the ppd files folder it will be inside "opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201401w/ppds/Epson" folder of your extracted folder
6. Extract Epson-L220_Series-epson-driver.ppd.gz.
7. Connect your printer
8. Delete the printer if it is automatically added
9. Go to printer settings
10. Add printer.
11. Espon 220 which will be listed. Select it.
    12 Go forward. You will get a radio option in next steps to select ppd file from your downloaded folder which is extracted before.
12. Finish installation and printer should be working

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and an Epson L220. For me the procedure was a little bit different:

1. I downloaded `epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm` from Espson driver support site.
2. In order to make it work in terminal I installed LSB package:

   ```
   wget launchpadlibrarian.net/233789933/lsb-release_9,20160110_all.deb
   ```
3. Then I deleted the printer because it was automatically added from settings.
4. I insert the printer with USB and added as explained by [@BapiSaha](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130953/618353) and it's working :D

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the .deb instead of .rpm
and double clicked on it.
Then I went to printer settings, find driver,  and chose the newly added driver.