# Printer connected properly, but can't print

Tags: drivers, usb, printing

I'm using an EPSON printer connected via USB. It's setting up successfully, accepting jobs, and instantly marking jobs as completed. But the printer isn't printing them (or showing any indication of receiving a job).

I've tried the following things:

1. Installing it with open-source drivers
2. Installing it with proprietary drivers
3. Using different USB ports (2.0 and 3.0)
4. Connecting it via Ethernet (didn't work, I also don't use WiFi so that's not an option)
5. Restarting jobs in the queue
6. All the steps under "USB printer" here show the printer is connected properly: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems
7. Printing on Windows with a different device (which works fine)

I've also tried the other DebuggingPrintingProblems wiki troubleshooting steps, but can't because I don't know how to retrieve the ID of the printer's queue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

### Environment

- Printer: Epson Stylus NX635
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- GUI: GNOME 3.36.3 with Regolith WM

Comment: Try sudo apt purge ippusbxd

Comment: @BernardDecock I ran that and tried printing after. Still no luck. Please provide more detailed steps if you have any.

Comment: Printer model? This is essential info!

Comment: Did you install the Epson-drivers? https://www.epson.eu/viewcon/corporatesite/kb/index/2369

Comment: I assume that printing a test-page doesn't succeed as well? Can you view the ink-levels in the properties-menu? Maybe you can find some help here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130922/problem-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-epson-l220-printer

Comment: @brian_p just added it to the description

Comment: @BernardDecock yes I've installed the drivers, as I've said. I've tried both the proprietary and open-source ones. I installed them via the "add printer" in the printer settings in GNOME. No a test page doesn't work either. Yes I've checked the ink levels on the machine and it's fine, and even if it weren't it should display a warning (it has no indication of receiving the job)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the solution was simple. For some reason you need to install the following package according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/763268/395029):

```sh
sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr
```

After that, you can go through the "Add printer" wizard in the printer settings, and it will install the correct drivers. Before this, whatever drivers it was installing didn't work.

Comment: In my case all jobs were stuck at "Processing" and this solved the issue - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Epson Stylus NX635 is an AirPrint device, so driverless printing is possible with a USB connection after purging ippusbxd.

- Switch the device off and disconnect from USB.
- Go to [this website](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) and install [ipp-usb](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/).
- Switch device on and reconnect to USB.
- Execute `driverless`. The output is a URI.
- Execute `lpadmin -p nx635 -v "URI" -E -m everywhere`. URI is what you got in the previous step.
- Test printing with `lp -d nx635 /etc/nsswitch.conf` and report back.