# print via canon ip2600 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, printing, canon

I plugged in the printer canon ip2600. The printer is listed when I want to print a document. But when I hit "print" ... nothing happens.

How can I print my document?

Comment: This may help...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288493/printer-connected-properly-but-cant-print

Comment: Or, point your browser to `http://localhost:631` the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) interface. You can configure your printer there.