# Unable to print document in linux 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, epson

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 lts. I plugin my Epson L220 printer .When i print a document, and any documents, the results on the paper always written "cups_hundleerror". And i have tried the same things on linux mint cinnamon 19.3, and the result is also same, the paper result written with "cups error". I try again to instal from cups web, but it doesn't work. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Epson L220 printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130922/problem-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-epson-l220-printer)

Answer (score 1):

Using [this tutorial](https://www.codentricks.com/how-to-install-epson-l220-driver-on-any-linux/) the OP was able to get his printer working correctly.

The key was to download the [Epson printer utility deb file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmn7p9p5rro4b00/epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb?dl=0)